# How to react to firebase auth email change

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'd like a safe way to update a user document in Firestore when a user changes their email address.

At the moment, the only way I can see to do it is by doing it client-side, after the `user.updateEmail()` is successfully called, but that call could fail for a variety of reasons, resulting in a mismatch between emails on the auth & the user's doc.

I was expecting to find a firebase function like `functions.auth().onChange()` but nothing like that seems to exist.

Comment: You can file a feature request to express interest in an auth onChange function.  It gets asked a lot.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Try using an AuthListener: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)